# Npm gets stuck when installing from git with ssh

Tags: git, npm

I'm trying to install a npm package from a git repository from our server. When I now do: `npm i git+ssh://username@domain.domain/path/to/rep` I get stuck at

`⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 42afea5547108748`

It just stops working, no errors shown.

thanks in advance

**Edit:**

- OS: MacOS Mojave
- Shell: zsh
- Auth: I do have a private key that I would have to type in my password. Alternatively I could type in the user password manually – To clarify, I do not actually authenticate. I assumed that it would prompt me. How would I do such a thing?
- Command Prompt: VS Code integrated terminal, newest version (not sure if that is the requested info)

If I press enter rapidly I get (note line 1):

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/elias/.ssh/shop_dev': -session dfa32709de1392f7
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session dfa32709de1392f7
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session dfa32709de1392f7
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session dfa32709de1392f7
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session dfa32709de1392f7
```

But no response when I enter the password. Neither certificates key nor with the passphrase of the user.

Comment: What's your OS and bash / command prompt type and version? How do you authenticate? I suspect either a problem or an invisible credentials prompt.

Comment: Added some info. Sorry I didn't suspect that the problem could be ssh

Comment: @G.Stoynev btw, I also suspect a problem :P

Answer (score 3):

Been through exactly same issue on a different OS and different bash.

Pls see this: [npm install not prompting passphrase required](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17387) - you can try typing your pass phrase when the hang occurs.

Or, to diagnose it another way, if you can, temporarily create and try with a key that is not password-protected. If that works, then you have to see which component acts as your ssh authentication agent (ssh-agent?).

In my case I reconfigured VSCode to use a different bash - one that I knew was playing nice with my passphrase-protected key.

Perhaps this URL will give you some pointers:
[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

-- **Edit 1** --

In your case (MacOS) it looks like the tool you may want to look into for help with providing the interaction is `sshpass` ([enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979))

-- **Edit 2** --

Since you confirmed that password-less key works just fine, you have at least these three options, assuming you are doing this interactively (for scripting options are different):

- figure out how to enter pass phrase while "hung", if possible (some people indicate it is - see the bug link above)
- Use an agent that plays nice with your shell; that worked for me, but I didn't like having that extra "agent". Instead I opted for...
- Reconfigure VS Code to use a different shell - one which plays nice with the password-protected key interaction. What worked for me was the `bash` included with my git install.

In your case (MacOS) it looks like the tool you may want to look into for help with providing the interaction is sshpass ([enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979))

Comment: hmpf: "if you can" I could but I shouldn't. It's even a stretch that I can use key auth and not have to type in the password :/

Comment: Added some stuff my my question

Comment: Why should you not quickly try a key that's not password-protected - this is just to zero down on the issue. Once you know, you will destroy it. Using sshpass is a similar alternative, but with it it's adding to the magic, rather than thinning it :-) In any case, I am only hoping that sharing what worked for me is of some help to you

Comment: Actually I spammed my key and it continued. Now I'm stuck at `⸨       ░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠴ extract:module-name: timing audit body Completed in 1ms`

Comment: This is really annoying -.-

Comment: So I did create a password-less key and everything went down without a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you but this issue seems to be global. It neither works with `bash` nor with the normal mac os terminal. Still, have an up-vote for your effort :). Also the point with the ssh-agent is that it saves the passphrase which we don't want. So the sshpass thingy also doesn't really fit our needs

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and this [post of GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) explains how to solve it very easily.

all you need is adding the following lines to this file `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{your private key file name}
```

Comment: But you would still need to enter the identity's password...

Comment: At least for the first time. But maybe a reasonable workaround for MacOs, or any other Os / desktop environment that support some type of secret storage, integrated with the ssh-agent.